# Copy file from USB driver in Android programmatically

Tags: android, usb

I am working with an Android device that has an extra USB port where you can insert a USB stick. I would like to copy a file from the USB stick to the internal storage of my Android device. I am using a piece of code like that.

```
...
UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(0);
UsbEndpoint endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);
UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device);
connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
```

If I understand correctly I need to use `connection.bulkTransfer` with the the  to get the file from the USB stick but I could not find any example code.

Can anyone help with that? Many thanks

Ps notice that using this [git project](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums) is not an option because the integration in my application did not work.

Comment: Given that [libaums uses connection.bulkTransfer](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums/blob/fc1fa24216f9fe6f874369741bb0b066396ccf2c/libaums/src/main/java/com/github/mjdev/libaums/usb/JellyBeanMr2Communication.kt) its unclear why that project isn't a valid option. Or for at least understanding how to build a minimal feature set for your needs.

Comment: Why so difficult? Doesn't ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE show the drive?

Comment: Well I tried to add the libaums project to mine but the compilation unfortunately did not work.

Comment: Thanks about ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, I can give it a try as second solution. My favorite solution would be to pull a file with a certain name from the USB stick. The task is pretty banal but seems to be pretty difficult in Android or I am missing something.

Comment: If it is only for one file use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and let the user choose the file.